# Can the microsoft stack really not scale?

Tags: asp.net, scalability

based on a recent article on MySpace blaming the microsoft stack not being able to easily scale [here](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/25/did-the-microsoft-stack-kill-myspace.html).

Is this true? Is scaling an app built on the microsoft stack (asp.net mvc here) nearly impossible? does php/LAMP really scale better than microsoft?

Comment: Voted as off topic.  The article in question has nothing to do with technology but is more about bad management, hiring difficulties and the weight of technical debt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The Microsoft stack can scale just fine.

You just have to have the right set of skills to do the job. Unfortunately MySpace didn't have the proper resources (or access to the proper resources because of physical location, according to their article) and they're blaming the technology stack.